# decltype for materialized prvalues member access behaves incorrectly

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
 
struct A { double x; };
int main() 
{

    const A && a1 = A();
    
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype((a1.x)), const double&>;
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype((std::move(a1).x)), const double&&>;
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype((A().x)), double>;
   
}

Output:

111
```

Shouldn't *decltype* in the last example return *double&&* since  according to [value categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). *A().x* is an *xvalue*

> xvalue
>
> a.m, the member of object expression, where a is an rvalue and m is a
> non-static data member of non-reference type;
>
> ...

Tested with gcc7.1;gcc5.2;clang3.8;gcc4.9;gcc4.8;gcc4.7 in the code snippet  of en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

Comment: I got "110" with [clang7](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JPmcWzzzIxx8Rzuq).

Comment: I got 111 with gcc 7.1;gcc5.2;clang3.8;gcc4.9;gcc4.8;gcc4.7

Comment: I'm testing with the compilers available in the code snippet page of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

Comment: Anyway I think the type should be `double&&`, unless cppreference.com is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going strictly by the standard, it appears you're right and it should be `double &&`. My chain of reasoning (all quotes from C++17 (n4659)):

#### 8.2.5 Class member access [expr.ref]

> 1 A postfix expression followed by a dot `.` or an arrow `->`, optionally followed by the keyword `template` (17.2),
>   and then followed by an *id-expression*, is a postfix expression. ...
>
> 2 For the first option (dot) the first expression shall be a glvalue having complete class type.
>
> 3 Abbreviating *postfix-expression.id-expression* as `E1.E2`, `E1` is called the *object expression*. ... The type and value category of `E1.E2` are determined as follows. In the remainder
>   of 8.2.5, *cq* represents either `const` or the absence of `const` and *vq* represents either `volatile` or the absence
>   of `volatile`. *cv* represents an arbitrary set of cv-qualifiers, as defined in 6.9.3.
>
> ...
>
> (4.2) If `E2` is a non-static data member and the type of `E1` is “*cq1 vq1* `X`”, and the type of `E2` is “*cq2 vq2* `T`”,
>   the expression designates the named member of the object designated by the first expression. If `E1` is
>   an lvalue, then `E1.E2` is an lvalue; otherwise `E1.E2` is an xvalue. ...

So if the left-hand side operand of `.` is an xvalue, so is the result of the entire `.` expression.

#### 8.2.3 Explicit type conversion (functional notation) [expr.type.conv]

> 1 A *simple-type-specifier* (10.1.7.2) or *typename-specifier* (17.6) followed by a parenthesized optional *expression-list*
>   or by a *braced-init-list* (the initializer) constructs a value of the specified type given the initializer. ...
>
> 2 ... the expression
>   is a prvalue of the specified type whose result object is direct-initialized (11.6) with the initializer.

So `A()` is a prvalue.

Finally:

#### 8 Expressions [expr]

> 10 Whenever a prvalue expression appears as an operand of an operator that expects a glvalue for that operand,
>   the temporary materialization conversion (7.4) is applied to convert the expression to an xvalue.

Taken together, this means that `A()` is a prvalue (from 8.2.3/2). Since `.` requires its LHS operand to be a glvalue, the temporary materialisation conversion is appplied (per 8/10) and the result is an xvalue. So, from 8.2.5/(4.2), since `E1` is an xvalue, so is `E1.E2`, which is `A().x` in your case.

As for `decltype`:

#### 10.1.7.2 Simple type specifiers [dcl.type.simple]

> 4 For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>
> ...
>
> (4.3) ... if `e` is an xvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;

Since in your case, `(A().x)` was determined to be an xvalue, its `dectlype` should be `double &&`.

Comment: I have reached the same conclusion following here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_member_access_operators and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization